# I have an error during the session, code 400, message Bad request version ('×«')

Tags: python, django, linux, docker

Let's me explain that. Few days ago I installed a django app with docker, I had no problem with that, and later I tried to add a security for **settings.py** and now I have an error

```
code 400, message Bad request version ('×«') 
You're accessing the development server over HTTPS, but it only supports HTTP.
```

and now when I start creating new app I have a same error but I did not add security for new app

So my files

```
db.sqlite3 manage.py requirements.txt  src  venv
```

I am using **django 4.0 with psycopg 2.9.3**

Next, when I am going to run a server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I have seen that

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you 
apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
March 27, 2023 - 09:17:44
Django version 4.0, using settings 'src.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

When I log in to the server **http://127.0.0.1:8000/**

I see on browser this **https://localhost:8000/**

and a same error code 400

Shoud i delete a docker?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are accessing https://localhost:8000/ while you should be accessing http://localhost:8000/. Note: it should be **http** and not **https**.

---

Also, if the security features you added are https related, then maybe you have problems with the settings.

To fix the HTTPS error, you should check your settings.py file and make sure that the SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT setting is set to False. Also, make sure that your Docker container is set up to use HTTP on port 8000.

If the error keeps happening, you might want to rebuild your Docker container with the correct settings.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Anyway, should I delete all images in docker?

Comment: You can. Or use `docker images` to check which one you want to delete. You will need to replace the current docker image in order to get a working docker container with the security changes you added.

Answer (score 1):

In `settings.py` try changing

> ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "https"

to

> ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL = "http"

Or Try running through different port eg. `python manage.py runserver 2000`

Comment: Probably, I found it. Thanks a lot friend. I tried running through different port. It helps me.

Comment: Hello, again!. I have one question. Right now my OS is Linux/Manjaro so. I recently deployed a django app with heroku and tweaked some details. Shoud I delete hosts on /etc/hosts ? Can you help me? it would be wonderful. Thanks